# Retrieving F-test statistic on fixed effects joint significance in -xtreg-

Tags: stata, estimation

I am running the equivalent of the following regression:

```
sysuse auto, clear

xtset rep78
xtreg mpg weight, fe
```

and I need to store the F-statistic on the F-test of joint significance of the model fixed effects (in this case, `F(4, 63) = 1.10` in the output).

I inspected the post-estimation documentation of `xtreg` and searched online, but I couldn't find any information on this.
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you refer to in the sample output for your fixed effects regression is

```
F test that all u_i=0: F(4, 63) = 1.10
```

You don't want to be looking in  `help xtreg postestimation` but rather in `help xtreg`, the output of which includes at the bottom the list of stored results returned in `e()`. Among those, in the section on `xtreg, fe` is

```
e(F_f)              F for u_i=0
```

If you are unfamiliar with working with stored results returned in `e()` you will want to review `help ereturn`.